# Dictionary initialization access to Key value

Tags: c#, dictionary, initialization

I have this situation :

```
public Class Device
{
}
public Class Response
{
   Response(Device device){ ... }
}

public class DeviceManager
{

private Dictionary<Device, Response> behaviours = new Dictionary<Device, Behaviour>{
{
new Device, new Response(...here I want the to send current key value !!!... )}
}
}
```

Can I access current value of key by current c# semantic means? I know I am very lazy.

Comment: What do you mean by "the current key value"? What key? You haven't explained this clearly at all... A short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, along with a clear explanation, would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: @Jon the "new Device()" is the current key value

Comment: Ah, I see. Um, just don't do it in a field initializer.

Comment: @Jon Just wondered if there is some trick to do that here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that in a field initializer. You'd have to put it in a constructor:

```
public class DeviceManager
{
    private Dictionary<Device, Response> behaviours =
        new Dictionary<Device, Behaviour>();

    public DeviceManager()
    {
        Device device = new Device();
        behaviours.Add(device, new Response(device));
    }
}
```

With C# 6 you *could* do it with an extension method on `Dictionary<Device, Response>`:

```
public static void Add(
    this Dictionary<Device, Response> dictionary,
    Device device)
{
    dictionary.Add(device, new Response(device));
}
```

Then:

```
... = new Dictionary<Device, Response> { new Device() };
```

... but I don't think I'd do that.

Comment: Thanks Jon, for the information about the new feature in C# 6.

Answer (score 0):

Because in this case providing means to understand the harness between devices by looking at the initialization was very important for me I ended up with this solution :

Actually you can tell Dictionary how to do initialization by introducing various **Add** methods :

```
public class Behaviours:Dictionary<Device, Response>
{
   new public void Add(Device d)
   {
       var r= new response(d);
       (this as Dictionary<Device, Response>).Add(d, r);
   }
}

...

private Behaviours _behaviours = new Behaviours{
  {new Device()},
  {new Device()},
  {new Device()},
}
```

In actual problem there are more parameters for device creation so by this way I create a set of behaviors which can be understood by one look.